# Copy multiple files using AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have to duplicate multiple files using an AppleScript. What this script should do is first, ask the user to select the folder which contains the files that have to be duplicated. Second, show a list of all of the files that there're in the folder that user have selected. In this step, the user can select multiple files. And the last step is duplicate the files. Here's t'he script I'm using:

```
--Get the folder
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder that contains the files to copy. In the next step you'll be able to select the files to copy.") as text

--Get the path to de destination folder of the files
set destination_folder to (path to home folder) as text

--Generate the list of files inside theFolder
tell application "Finder"
    set theItems to items of folder theFolder
    set theNames to {}
    repeat with anItem in theItems
        set end of theNames to name of anItem
    end repeat
end tell

-Let user select the files of the list
choose from list theNames with prompt "Select the files" OK button name "OK" cancel button name "Cancel" with multiple selections allowed

tell result
    if it is false then error number -128 -- cancel
    set theChoices to it
end tell

if (count of theChoices) is greater than or equal to 1 then
repeat with aChoice in theChoices
    set thisItem to theFolder & aChoice
    -- do something with thisItem
    duplicate thisItem to destination_folder
end repeat
end if
```

The problem is that when the srcipt has to run the line "copy thisItem to destination_folder" it crashes. Here's the oputput that generates AppleScript Editor when I try to run:

```
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
    choose from list {"Obres.xlsx", "Programa_sardanes", "Sardanes.xlsx"} with prompt "Escull els arxius o l'arxiu que vols afegir" OK button name "Acceptar" cancel button name "Cancelar" with    multiple selections allowed
    --> {"Sardanes.xlsx"}
-- 'core'\'clon'{ 'insh':'utxt'("Macintosh HD:Users:Joan:"), '----':'utxt'("Macintosh HD:Users:Joan:MEGA:Sardanes.xlsx"), &'subj':null(), &'csig':65536 }
    --> error number -1700 from "Macintosh HD:Users:Joan:MEGA:Sardanes.xlsx" to reference
Result:
error "Can't generate \"Macintosh HD:Users:Joan:MEGA:Sardanes.xlsx\" on the type reference." number -1700 from "Macintosh HD:Users:Joan:MEGA:Sardanes.xlsx" to reference
```

I have been trying several hours to solve this problem but I don't know where is the error on the script. I hope someone could help me. And if someone knows a much more simple way to do this would be helpful also. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some small changes to your script and it should work now...

Basically, you were missing a couple small portions. The "duplicate" command is a function of the "Finder", so I added a "Tell application "Finder"" to the duplicate portion. You were also storing your path to your file and folder as text, I modified them to be referenced as "alias".

```
on run
--Get the folder
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select the folder that contains the files to copy. In the next step you'll be able to select the files to copy.") as text

--Get the path to de destination folder of the files
set destination_folder to (path to home folder)

--Generate the list of files inside theFolder
tell application "Finder"
    set theItems to items of folder theFolder
    set theNames to {}
    repeat with anItem in theItems
        set end of theNames to name of anItem
    end repeat
end tell

--Let user select the files of the list
choose from list theNames with prompt "Select the files" OK button name "OK" cancel button name "Cancel" with multiple selections allowed

tell result
    if it is false then error number -128 -- cancel
    set theChoices to it
end tell

if (count of theChoices) is greater than or equal to 1 then
    repeat with aChoice in theChoices
        set thisItem to (theFolder & aChoice) as alias
        -- do something with thisItem
        tell application "Finder" to duplicate thisItem to destination_folder
    end repeat
end if
end run
```